# Wordpress, I don't want to display the featured image when I query custom post types

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

How can I stop the featured image from displaying in my custom post types queries?

my code when quering

```
<?php $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                $loop = new WP_Query( array(
                'post_type' => array(
                    'weddings',
                    'e_shoots_and_couples',
                    'kids_familiy',
                    'portraits',
                    'other_shoots'              
                ),
                'posts_per_page' => 10,
                'paged' => $paged
                ) ); ?>

    <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

            <?php the_title( '<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="' . get_permalink() . '" title="' . the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h2>' ); ?><div id="slider-date"><?php  echo get_the_date(); ?></div>

            <div class="entry-content">
                <?php the_content(); 

                /*$content = get_the_excerpt();
                $postOutput = preg_replace('/<img[^>]+./','', $content);
                echo $postOutput;*/




                ?>
            </div>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Thanks

Comment: This needs much _much_ more information. Code, links, explanations, anything.

Comment: I've added my query with the loop above

Comment: This code is showing the featured image? Are you sure? I don't think it should. Where exactly?

Comment: This is exactly my point, it's showing up even though I'm not telling it to show.

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look as the link [add theme support--Post Thumbnails](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_theme_support#Post_Thumbnails)

You can set thumbnail support for specific post types or all post type by using the add_theme_support function in functions.php file of your theme.

This feature enables post-thumbnail support for a Theme. This feature became available with Version 2.9. Note that you can optionally pass a second argument with an array of the post types for which you want to enable this feature.

```
add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
```

To enable only for Posts:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'post' ) );
```

Or only Pages:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'page' ) );
```

Enable for Posts and "movie" post type but not for Pages.

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'post', 'movie' ) );
```

This feature must be called before the init hook is fired. That means it needs to be placed directly into functions.php or within a function attached to the after_setup_theme hook:

For custom post types, you can also add post thumbnails using the register_post_type function as well.